# В чем разница дистрибутивов Debian?

Tags: linux, debian

В чем разница между:

1. https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-dvd/
2. https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/current-live/amd64/iso-hybrid/
3. https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/10.4.0-live+nonfree/amd64/iso-hybrid/
4. https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/10.4.0+nonfree/amd64/iso-dvd/

??????

Comment: 1 и 4 это одно и то же, 2 и 3 это одно и то же

Comment: Это всё одно и то же, запаковано по-разному.